# tinymce iframe height

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinyMCE, and have more than 100 texareas on the page. Iframe, which is created after initialization, has min-width=62px, even there is only a line inside. Can I somehow decrease this value?

And the second question, inside Iframe there is HTML page with body style="padding-bottom:50px". Is it possible to decrease it, otherwise textarea takes much place :/

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   autoresize_bottom_margin : 10,       
   theme : 'advanced',
   plugins : 'autoresize',
   ...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. Here it is:

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {

          var new_val = '30px';

          // adjust table element
          var elem = document.getElementById(ed.id + '_tbl');
          elem.style.height = new_val;

          // adjust iframe element
          var iframe = document.getElementById(ed.id + '_ifr');
          iframe.style.height = new_val;
      });
   }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Thariama. Thanks for response. I have put console.log(iframe.style.height) after your code. It shows me in console 30px, but the area itself is 62px. Seems like it changes the height after oninit function. Okay, even if it is working, this 30 px will be only when initialized, later while changing text it becomes bigger, because of padding-bottom, I described in question.